# How can I convert a List<String> to an xml document?

Tags: c#, xml

I have this current code:

```
List<string> BugWSResponseList1 = new List<string>();
Logger.Write("\n\n" + DateTime.Now + " : " + 
             " : START : Creation of a set of Bugs via bug.Add API");
BugWSResponseList1 = CreateBugs(FilePath_EXPRESS_API_BugAdd_CreateBugs_DataFile);
```

I would like to convert the `List<string> BugWSResponseList1` to an xml document.

Can you please suggest a way to do it?

Comment: Look into this [msdn c-serialize-liststring-to-xml](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0a5aa658-7276-42e5-9d9e-b786694d6020/c-serialize-liststring-to-xml). You will get many options to do it.

Answer (score 5):

You can quite easily use LINQ for this:

```
var x = new XElement("bugs", 
    BugWSResponseList1.Select(t => new XElement("bug", t)));

Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
```

Answer (score 2):

If you store the list in a class you can write something like:

```
[XmlType("Foo")]
public class Foo {

  [XmlArray("Items")]
  [XmlArrayItem("Item")]
  public List<string> Data {get; set;}

}
```

This will result in something like:

```
<Foo>
  <Items>
    <Item>Rock</Item>
    <Item>Paper</Item>
    <Item>Scissor</Item>
    <Item>Lizard</Item>
    <Item>Spock</Item>
  </Items>
</Foo>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [Linq to xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx)

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

XElement xml = new XElement("BugWSResponses",
                   (from x in BugWSResponseList1 select
                    new XElement("Bug", x)));
```

Answer (score 1):

code example

```
List<string> ExampleList = new List<string>{"1", "b"};

var xml = ExampleList.SerializeToXml();
```

The serializer

```
public static string SerializeToXml<T>(this T obj)
{
    var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(obj.GetType());
    using (var writer = new StringWriter())
    using (var stm = new XmlTextWriter(writer))
    {
        serializer.WriteObject(stm, obj);
        return writer.ToString();
    }
}
```

results in

```
<ArrayOfstring xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"><string>1</string><string>b</string></ArrayOfstring>
```